# With React, how can I horizontally scroll to the selected item in a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The idea is to have a horizontal scrollable list, and when selecting an item, the list scrolls to that item, which should make the item centered in the list.

I have tried to create an example using React, but I struggle to calculate the `scrollLeft` value.

http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/zug42kh8/

```
const scrollContainer = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.scrollRef);
const activeItem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.activeRef);

const scrollRect = scrollContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
const activeRect = activeItem.getBoundingClientRect();
const activeWidth = activeRect.width;
const activeLeft = activeRect.left;
const activeRight = activeRect.right;
const scrollWidth = scrollContainer.scrollWidth;
const scrollLeft = scrollRect.left;

scrollContainer.scrollLeft = (scrollWidth / 2) + (activeLeft / 2) + (scrollLeft * 2);
```

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zug42kh8/90/)

First of all, yeah, calculating:

```
scrollLeftPosition: activeRect.left - scrollRect.left - (scrollRect.width / 2) + (activeRect.width / 2)
```

Second. I changed manipulation with scrollLeft to "+=". As you should not just assign in your case, but take in account current scroll state.

```
scrollContainer.scrollLeft += this.state.scrollLeftPosition;
```

And the main point: you called this.centerActiveItem() before new state applied. this.setState is async function. You need to pass function to call it after updating state.

```
this.setState({}, callback);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. Is there an easy way to add an animation to this?

Comment: @RemiSture In fact, there's an easier way :) jsfiddle.net/zug42kh8/92  There's a cool method, quite well supported: element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"});   This works like magic :)

Comment: Or just use `scroll-behavior: smooth;` on the container, but that has poor browser support :)

Comment: really nice way of making this work, I am although having a bit of trouble putting this to work with hooks, you wouldn't be able to make this work with hooks @Anarion? thanks